# Cloud SQL: Get an alert when a maintenance is scheduled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-monitoring

I use Cloud SQL with a Fixed maintenance window. I want an alert to fire up on Google Cloud monitoring when the database is scheduled for the maintenance in order to notify the individuals interested.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is feasible only through email for now, and not through a GCS monitoring based solution.